# Trigger Event on Ajax generated Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can't use any Event (eg. onlick) on any ajax generated element. I read about jQuery's ".on" function, but I need to use something like `<div id="myId_1234" onlick="doStuff()">`.
The Id of the Element is random, so I can't use

```
`$('.some-parent-class').on('click', '.element', function() {// DO STUFF!});`
```

I hope someone can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a class to it then and target using a jQuery class selector. When you say it is 'ajax generated' what do you mean?

Comment: explain more... Why you can't use class?

Comment: Why is the id random?

Comment: OP here. Ajax generated means, I call a PHP file which "echo's" some html code. This code is the response of the ajax call and I simply append it to a parent element. I cant use a class because every element is unique. (They are chat windows and should be individually closed when you click on their header). The id is the user's id (unique)

Comment: @ArEsiiX My answer emulates the "Ajax generated" thing by dynamically creating a div element and then attaching the event listener to it. You can always use jQuery to retrieve the component ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach the event handler to your element in the AJAX response before adding it to the DOM by using

```
$(responseHtml).find('some selector').on('click', handler);
```

There is most likely one or more [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) that will work for you.

Ex: id begins with selector

```
$(responseHtml).find('div[id^=myId]').on('click', handler);
```

If you cannot differentiate which element in the response you need with a css selector you will have to modify the server script generating the HTML with a unique id or class that matches a pattern you can look for.

**EDIT**

You CAN use a css class to identify each element.  use:

```
$('.myCloseButtonClass').on('click', function(){ $(this).parent.hide(); });
```

The key here is the `this` object.  It will reference the specific element that was clicked thereby allowing you to close only the chat window that contains the clicked close button.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVRLU/3/) using AJAX echo

Answer (score 0):

I am simulating the Ajax Generated part by dynamically generating a clickable DIV element.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#container").append(
    $('<div>').attr('id', 'randomId').html('New element')
);

$("#randomId").click( function(){
    alert('Clicked!!!');
});
```

EDIT: Same example using class instead of Id:

```
$("#container").append(
    $('<div>').attr('id', 'randomId').addClass('parent-class').html('New element')
);

$(".parent-class").click( function(){
    var clickedElementId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert('Element with ID ' + elementId + ' Clicked!!!');
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVRLU)

Comment: to clarify my question: I got a facebook like chat. Every chat window should be closed by clicking on the "x" icon (id=random, window id=random). The windows are generated after the site loaded. How should i use $("#randomId").click on a undefined number of elements? <div onclick=""> seems to be the only way to do this for me?

Comment: @ArEsiiX Have you seen the second example using a CSS class instead of the ID? $(".parent-class").click( function(){...} This will fire the event for every element assigned to the "parent-class" CSS class. onclick attribute is not the right way to do this. You have to use dynamically attached event listeners. Your HTML code should not have any event listeners.

Comment: Do you want to close ever chat window by clicking on one? Class won't work. How can I use $("#randomId").click on a undefined number of elements?

Comment: @ArEsiiX, does the random id adhere to any sort of pattern, like "myId_001", "myId_002", "myId_999"?

Comment: no, its the users facebook id.. which is pretty random :D

Comment: @ArEsiiX, is there only one chat window and therefore only one close button per AJAX response?

Comment: Yep, if there are multiple windows open, the ajax request will be executed multiple times. One Window will be generated per request.

Comment: @ArEsiiX Why not just assign the same CSS class to all chat windows and use jQuery to listen to the click events? Why is this not good for you?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the click event properly? I want every window to be treated independently. If you want to close one window, only one should be closed. Does this work with jQuery?

Comment: @ArEsiiX Yes, the click event only applies to the element clicked.  It does not fire for each element that was selected when only one is clicked.  The `this` object will be the element clicked.

Comment: @ArEsiiX I've just edited the answer to demonstrate how to use the $(this) selector within the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.some-parent-class').on('click', 'this put your id input', function() {// DO STUFF!});
```

proib with this......

Comment: I need the onclick event on the element itself, because I got no chance to get the id. (2 files)

Comment: so , after append the response page from php ajax, you should find the element in the part when you append the page, if the control is in the page you retrieve and have id unique is more easy to get it, like $("#uniqueid").on("click", funcion(){ // do stuff});, if you want too,  you can get the input using find jquery , in this case you should use the correct selector of your control...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<div class="myBoxes">
    <div id="oneBox" onclick="myFunc(this.parentNode);">
        <p>Some content..</p>
    </div>
</div>

function myFunc(){
    // Code goes here
   alert('function fired!');
}
```